# Performance Problem

Tags: performance-tuning

I've written the code that follows:

```
tails = Function[l, If[ l == {}, {}, Prepend[tails[Drop[l, 1]], l]]]

Te = Composition[AllTrue[PrimeQ], Map[FromDigits], tails, IntegerDigits]

Timing[Select[Range[2, 10^6], Te]]
```

This takes around 21seconds on my computer, but the equivalent Haskell code takes 1second.

Is there something I can do to improve the performance of the code in Mathematica?

Comment: What's the tl;dr of what this code is supposed to do? In case we don't feel like reverse engineering it...

Comment: You can get somewhere by replacing `tails` with `NestList[#[[2 ;;]] &, #, Length@# - 1] &`. `Prepend` is generally pretty slow, and should be avoided in functions that get used repeatedly.

Answer (score 9):

[Not really an answer but too long for a comment.]

Not sure if there is a direct Haskell-like way that can be made quite that fast (I guess it depends on exactly how equivalent is that equivalent Haskell code). Here is an approach that short-circuites when it hits a non-prime.

```
Te4[n_?PrimeQ] :=
 Module[{dig = Rest[IntegerDigits[n]]}, 
  While[Length[dig] > 0 && PrimeQ[FromDigits[dig]], 
   dig = dig[[2 ;; -1]]];
  Length[dig] == 0]
Te4[_Integer] = False;
```

Check speed.

```
Timing[t4 = Select[Range[2, 10^6], Te4];]

(* Out[199]= {1.055633, Null} *)
```

Compare in speed to original version.

```
tails = Function[l, If[l == {}, {}, Prepend[tails[Drop[l, 1]], l]]];
Te1 = Composition[AllTrue[PrimeQ], Map[FromDigits], tails, 
   IntegerDigits];
Timing[t1 = Select[Range[2, 10^6], Te1];]

(* Out[207]= {13.95006, Null} *)
```

Check correctness.

```
t4 === t1

(* Out[208]= True *)
```

Answer (score 7):

*Updated to use PrimePi per @MichaelE2's helpful comment!*

Here's another approach. First, let's get a list of all the primes, and then define a prime vector where 1 indicates the index is a prime:

```
primeList = Prime[Range[PrimePi[10^7]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

primeVector = ConstantArray[0, 10^7]; //AbsoluteTiming
primeVector[[primeList]] = 1; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.21477, Null}
>
> {0.022988, Null}
>
> {0.018425, Null}

Now, rather than create a predicate to test each element, I will use a predicate that works on lists:

```
primeModQ[p_List, pow_] := primeVector[[Mod[p, 10^pow]]]
```

The function `primeModQ` determines which elements of `p` are primes modulo `10^pow`, returning a list of the same length where `1` indicates the number is a prime, and `0` indicates the number is composite. Finally, I will use `primeModQ` inside a [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold):

```
r1 = Fold[
    Pick[#, primeModQ[#, #2], 1]&,
    Pick[Range[10^6], primeVector[[Range[10^6]]], 1],
    Range[5, 1, -1]
]; //AbsoluteTiming

Length[r1]
```

> {0.014613, Null}
>
> 1672

The above is in agreement with @DanielLichtblau's answer. Let's try primes up to 10^7:

```
r7 = Fold[
    Pick[#, primeModQ[#, #2], 1]&,
    Pick[Range[10^7], primeVector[[Range[10^7]]], 1],
    Range[6, 1, -1]
]; //AbsoluteTiming

Length[r7]
```

> {0.273536, Null}
>
> 3984

**Addendum**

A much faster algorithm is to start with single digits instead. Here is a version that does this:

```
Clear[p]
p[0] = Prime @ Range @ PrimePi[10];
p[n_] := p[n] = Join[
    p[n-1],
    q[p[n-1], n]
]

q[plist_, n_] := With[
    {next = Range[10^n, 9 10^n, 10^n]},
    With[
        {new = Tuples[Unevaluated[Plus[next, plist]]]},
        Pick[new,PrimeQ[new]]
    ]
]
```

Here is the number of primes less than $10^6$:

```
Length @ p[5] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.004048, 1672}

And the number of primes less than $10^7$ and $10^8$:

```
Length @ p[6] //AbsoluteTiming
Length @ p[7] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.012358, 3984}
>
> {0.030985, 8779}

Comment: `primeList = Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[10^7]}]` is a bit faster.